# How to create port 5078 in Google compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, port, google-compute-engine

I have 4 Google compute engine instances and I want to add port 5078 to my instances. I think I need to add some firewall rules. I tried to that but I can't see my port 5078 in my instance. can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your console and select your project in which you want to open a port.
2. Go to VPC networking and open a firewall from the list.
3. Click on create firewall rule and give a unique name and don’t change any default values.
4. In the targets section select “specific target tags” and in the next column specify the target tag names which you specified in your instances.
5. In the Source filter select “IP ranges” and give the IP address as 0.0.0.0/0.
6. Next in the protocols and ports select “Specific protocols and ports'' and select TCP and give the port number as 5078.
7. Click on create and the firewall rule will be created.
8. If you want to check whether your firewall rule will be added or not. open your instances and click on three dots and open view network details
   And you will find the Under firewall and route details click on firewall rules and you can see the firewall rule with port number 5078.

For more information please refer the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create firewall rule allowing ingress on the port 5078.

Follow below instructions :

1. Navigate to the Networking > VPC network.
2. Select Firewall.
3. Click on Create Firewall Rule.
4. Provide a unique name and description.
5. Then select Ingress and allow it.
6. In order to apply this rule to specific VM instance, under Targets drop down select Specified target tags.
7. Then enter the Target tags. This tags will be used to apply the new firewall rules onto an instance of your choice.
8. In source Ip ranges give 0.0.0.0/0 for a source from any network.
9. Under Protocols and ports, select Specified protocols and ports then check the tcp checkbox and add the port number 5078 in it.
10. Click create.
11. Add the target tag created to the VM instance by editing details and adding the tags to network tag.

Follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) for the reference.